# Flask-admin - how to change formatting of columns - get URLs to display

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

Question on flask-admin. I setup flask-admin and one of the models i created is pulling urls and url titles from a mysql database.  Using flask-admin, how to i get flask-admin to render the urls instead of just text? So make it easier for users to just click on the link from the flask-admin app.  Thank you.

I found something on the flask-admin site called column formatters, but not sure how to implement.  Does anyone have an example they can share? Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you need? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 21):

Assuming you have a view named MyView, and your model has fields url, and urltitle then below would work.

```py
from flask import Markup

class MyView(ModelView)
    @staticmethod
    def _user_formatter(view, context, model, name):
        if model.url:
           markupstring = "<a href='%s'>%s</a>" % (model.url, model.urltitle)
           return Markup(markupstring)
        else:
           return ""

    column_formatters = {
        'url': _user_formatter
    }
```

Comment: How do I import `Markup`?

Comment: @Daniel - It's `from flask import Markup`.